# Как получить значение по ID, использую C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

```
var result = (await App.Database.GetItemsAsync()).Where(x => x.ID == 0 );
```

Как получить значение по ID, использую C#? может что-то в конце кода нужно добавить?
по факту нужно чтобы в переменной `result` оказалось значение из колонки AGE базы данны.

Comment: `.Where` замените на `.FirstOrDefault`, тогда вы получите 1 объект с указанным ID, дальше берите из него все, что вашей душе будет угодно.

Comment: этот вариант возьму на заметку, спасибо. Просто здесь больше операции придется сделать. Сейчас опробовал вот такой вариант ```var result = (await App.Database.GetItemsAsync()).Where(x => x.ID == 0 ).Select(x => x.Age);``` но не сработал.

Comment: как мне кажется в вашем случае можно воспользоваться [Single](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.single?view=netframework-4.7.2): `(await App.Database.GetItemsAsync()).Single(x => x.ID == 0 ).Age`;

Comment: ваш пример следует читать так, найди мне все все строки подходящие под условие `id == 0`, после этого выполняется проекция, результат будет содержать *список* возрастов.

Comment: Bald ваш пример работает. Но в результате что-то непонятное из-за этого ломается следующий код за этим. сейчас попробую посмотреть, что-там. Должно быть, пример```30```

Comment: когда отвечаете кому-то в комментариях не забывайте писать `@Ник_пользователя`, что бы данный участник получил оповещение от системы, пример @EvgeniyZ тоже должен был сработать

Comment: @Bald ни смог ) увидеть) что-там. не приходит результат. подскажите что будет в переменной ```result```

Comment: напишите что вы хотите сделать и что не получается: добавьте в вопрос пример данных с которыми надо работать, и остальную информацию...

Comment: @Bald ошибка в ИД, в базе данных начинается нумерация с 1, а не с нулю )) Ваш пример работает. Спасибо большое за помощь. Странно что вы этого не заметили внимательньей нужно быть ;) еще раз спасибо большое.

Comment: @Bald `(await App.Database.GetItemsAsync()).Single(x => x.ID == 0 ).Age` - это разве не выкачает всю таблицу из БД в память ради одного поля конкретной строчки?

Comment: @tym32167 не знаю, возможно. что скрывается за `GetItemsAsync` я не знаю...

Comment: `Select`, `Where` и т. п. возвращают _коллекцию_ объектов (`IEnumerable`). Методы `First`, `Single` и т. п., а также вызов вашего свойства `Age` возвращают _один_ объект. Вероятно, из-за этого ваш последующий код ломается.