# Как в picker подгрузить значение из локальной базы данных?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

есть picker на C# написан

```
var AgeList = new List<string>();
            AgeList.Add("1");
            AgeList.Add("2");
            AgeList.Add("3");
            AgeList.Add("4");
            AgeList.Add("5");
            AgeList.Add("6");
            AgeList.Add("7");

            var picker = new Picker { Title = "Select", TitleColor = Color.Red };
            picker.ItemsSource = AgeList;
            picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "Age");
```

есть локальная база данных, куда сохраняются значение из picker в таблицу TableAge. У таблицы есть ID и колонка Age. Сохранённое значение будет хранится в колонке Age c ID=1.

Есть модуль с помощью которого можно сохранять и получать значения

```
public class TableAge
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

    }
```

Ну и наконец-то) значение которое хранится в БД в колонке Age c ID=1 нужно подгрузить в picker.

Так же при изменении пользователем значения в picker, новое значение к примеру "3", значение должно сохранится в БД в колонку Age c ID=1.

Любая помощь, ссылки(хотя с доками я уже ознакомился понял на сколько смог), примеры, логику, что-нибудь. вобщем любой помощи буду благодарен.

Comment: Пробовали гуглить `название_вашей_базы c#`?

Comment: @tym32167 если вы имеете ввиду эти статьи: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-items и https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource то их, да, нагуглил и ознакомился. Но сложно понять каша в голове.

Comment: по этим ссылкам есть работа с вашей БД (которую вы так и не назвали)?

Comment: @tym32167 судя по предыдущим вопросам, это SQLite: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970137/Как-получить-значение-по-id-использую-c

Comment: @AlexKrass давайте дадим шанс автору вопроса улучшить вопрос, а то если на каждый вопрос бегать проверять что автор имел ввиду, то никакого времени на ответы не хватит :)

Comment: @tym32167, @AlexKrass да это Sqlite. Хм, просто мне кажется в этом коде нужно привязать BindingContext с модулем и это нужно сделать на C#, подумал что вы говоря о базе имели ввиду что-то другое так как я не видел и не вижу прямой логической связи с БД так как вся работа с данными ```picker``` строится на модуле```public class TableAge
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

    }``` если бы вы написали за место ;) "базы" это "базы данных" то возможно, мне было бы понятно :)

Comment: давайте так. Вот вам надо понять, как получить данные из sqlite. Открываете гугл, забиваете туда `xamarin sqlite c#`, открываете первые 2-3 ссылки, читаете, пробуете это же самое сделать в своем проекте и если не получится, то пишете в вопрос, что мол "я смотрел вот это (ссылки), пробовал вот это (ваш код), получил вот такой результат (ошибка или что там у вам может быть), а мне надо вот такой, помогите"

Comment: я это говорю, так как у вас в вопросе нет никакого намека даже на самостоятельные попытки решить свою проблему, а если вы не пытались ничего, какой смысл кому то пытаться это сделать за вас? \

Comment: @tym32167 не в коем случае не хотел чтобы казалось что мне нужно чтобы за меня все сделали. На самом деле когда я пишу вопрос стараюсь убрать всё лишние(то что не сработало), чтобы по коду не казалось что я просто перебираю варианты(на бум делаю). Хотя в какой-то степени оно так есть(перебираю варианты), но это потому что, плохо знаю озы(очень плохо). Здесь можете сказать, так учите озы! и вы будите правы. учу потихоньку. Ладно я отдалился, в любом случае прошу прошения за нечётко поставленные вопросы. Буду стараться, и может когда нибудь смогу помочь вам в решении вопроса.

Comment: Все эти статьи читал https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm и https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases и https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx в проекте реализовано сохранение удаления, обновления по этой статье https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases и все хорошо работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем сделал так.

По условию у меня есть элемент с ID=1.

Так как ID элемента известно то просто делаем запрос в БД и получаем значения поля которое нам нужно. :)

```
var age = (await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncD()).Single(x => x.ID == 1).Age;
```

Теперь известны все данные по элементу. :)

(здесь я могу путаться в формулировке чуть-чуть так что будьте острожнее)
Теперь создаем новый picker по шаблону который у нас был условлен изначально.

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PagePicker
{
BindingContext = new Models.PagePicker { ID = 1, Age = age } as Models.PagePicker
});
```

Вот и все, значение из БД подгружено в Picker :) всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно при использовании какой-либо технологии, желательно понимать как она примерно устроена и иметь под рукой какой-нибудь хороший ресурс. В противном случае, если недостаточно опыта, попытка взять ее с наскока может быть даже хуже, чем изучить мануал с нуля. Поэтому начну с ресурса, который лично мне нравится: https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/

**Небольшое примечание**

Не имеет смысла создавать таблицу для одного единственного значения с постоянным ID. Обычно в этом случае заводится специальная таблица для настроек Settings. Она могла бы выглядеть так:

```
public class TableSettings
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

И запросы уже были бы без ID и ненужного никому автоинкремента, который не используется:

```
class SettingsRepository {
    SQLiteConnection database;
    public SettingsRepository ()
    {
        database = //подключение к БД
    }

    public string GetAge()
    {
        return database.Table<TableSettings>().Where(p => p.Key == "Age").Select(p => p.Value).First();
    }
    public void SaveAge(string newAge)
    {
        var item = database.Table<TableSettings>().Where(p => p.Key == "Age").Select(p => p);
        item.Value = newAge;
        database.Update(item);
    }
}
```

**Теперь к задаче**

Она выглядит слишком просто, по отношению к уже написанному коду. Поэтому у некоторых участников есть весомый повод пропустить вопрос, так как она больше подходит под определение "работа за автора".

Я возьму за основу ваш код, в него добавится всего пара простых строк, ссылки на источники которых вы уже сами привели даже.

```
SettingsRepository repository = new SettingsRepository();

public void SomeFunc(){
    var AgeList = new List<string>();
    AgeList.Add("1");
    AgeList.Add("2");
    AgeList.Add("3");
    AgeList.Add("4");
    AgeList.Add("5");
    AgeList.Add("6");
    AgeList.Add("7");
    AgeList.Add(repository.GetAge());

    var picker = new Picker { Title = "Select", TitleColor = Color.Red };
    picker.ItemsSource = AgeList;
    picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "Age");

    picker.SelectedIndexChanged += picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repository.SaveAge(picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

Comment: а что так синхронно то всё? :)

Comment: @tym32167 первый раз вижу Xamarin, руки до него так и не дошли. Мне кажется это не должны быть проблемой на локальной БД в контексте этого кода.

Comment: к вашему коду претензий никаких, я просто сходил по [ссылке от автора](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) и там прямо асинхронные вызовы, копируй не хочу, оч похожие на ваши, потому и подумал, что мы с вами одно и то же прочитали

Comment: @tym32167 не, ссылка от автора появилась уже после того, как я написал ответ. В качестве источника брал сайт, который указал в ответе. Там тоже есть [SQLite асинхронные методы](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/7.4.php), но я не стал с ними разбираться и воспользовался только [Picker](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/3.11.php) и [обычным SQLite подключением](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/7.2.php).